# How to check iOS version of a device for Game Center?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, game-center

I have implemented Game Center within my app and if I run it on devices lower than iOS 8.1, it throws me an error saying something along the lines of that this feature isn't available on devices lower than iOS 8.1. I have a button which opens up the leaderboard, so how can I effectively achieve saying something like if (iOS < 8.1) { leaderboard.button =  disabled}? Or is there a better way to just stop leaderboard from not loading up at all on devices lower than iOS 8.1?

Edit: Error that I get `'Menu' is only available on OS 8.0 and newer`. But if I write `@available(iOS 8.0, *)` on top of the class, I get rid of this error. However, if I ran the app on iOS < 8.0, and hitted the leaderboard button, the app crashes. `Menu` is the class in which I have Game Center implemented.

Comment: I have added the error @matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it :

```
if Float(UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion) < 8.1
{ leaderboard.button = disabled }
```

Comment: Thank You man. This worked like a charm :)